# Why am I getting this warning about my app delegate and CLLocationManageDelegate?

Tags: iphone

Observe this perfectly simple UIViewController subclass method:

```
-(IBAction)launchSearch
{
    OffersSearchController *search = [[OffersSearchController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"OffersSearchView" bundle:nil];
    EverWondrAppDelegate *del = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [del.navigationController pushViewController:search animated:YES];
    [search release];
}
```

On the line where I get *del, I am getting a compiler warning that reads, `Type 'id <UIApplicationDelegate>' does not conform to the 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' protocol`. In fact, my app delegate DOES conform to that protocol, AND what I'm doing here has nothing at all to do with that. So what's up with that message?

Secondary question: sometimes I can get to my navigationController via `self.navigationController`, and sometimes I can't, and have to go to my app delegate's property to get it like I'm doing here. Any hint about why that is would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
EverWondrAppDelegate *del = (EverWondrAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

With regards to your second question: no idea why this would be happening.